# Tensorflow-gpu installation issue on ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a linux machine running Ubuntu16.04, NVIDIA GEFORCE1060. I am running python3.6 (installed using anaconda) and CUDA9.1

I was happily coding in tensorlow with CPU with no issues. Then I wanted to install `tensorflow-gpu` and that's where I am having issues.

First installed cudnn7.1.2 successfully (`make` and run `mnist-cudnn` completed successfully)

`pip3 install tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

---

`import tensorflow as tf`

I am getting the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/bony/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Any help to resolve this and get me going on `tensorflow-gpu` will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- Check this github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15604
- You said you have installed cude9.1 but it is still showing that you have cuda9.0
- And check whether tensor-flow version you are using is compatible with cuda9.1 or not because many of the comments say that tensor-flow expects cuda9.0 and not cuda9.1
- If you are using anaconda then you can use the following command:
  1] [conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu)
  2] [conda install -c aaronzs tensorflow-gpu](https://anaconda.org/aaronzs/tensorflow-gpu)
- I think the above command also installs the cuda-toolkit and does all the required configuration for you which makes your life easier

Answer (score 0):

- I have the same issue with you on Ubuntu 16.04
- This my solution
- First,on the official web page part of [NVIDIA requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) we can know :

  - CUDA® Toolkit 9.0.
  - cuDNN v7.0.
  - GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher for building from source and 3.5 or higher for our binaries
- So uninstall Cuda9.1.

  - If you do not know how to uninstall,you can install `Synaptic Package Manager` in Ubuntu Software,and Search `cuda` and select `Mark for complete removal`
  - Apply
  - Reload `Synaptic Package Manager`
  - Select Cuda-9.0 `Mark for install`
  - Apply
- Install cnDNN v7.0

  - I had download `cuDNN v7.0.5 Developer Library for Ubuntu16.04 (Deb)` ,because it is the latest version cuDNN v7.0 for Cuda-9.0
- Install `cuda-command-line-tools`

  `sudo apt-get install cuda-command-line-tools`

  - If can not find `cuda-command-line-tools`

    `sudo apt-cache search cuda-command-line-tool`

    And select install `cuda-command-line-tool-9.0`
- Follow official document,add its path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:}/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64`
- I am using Anaconda3, i use conda command create environment include py3.5 name py35.
- So,i use `source activate py35` and use `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`
  .
- You can select [tensorflow-gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) which one support you python version.
- [Validate your installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip)

  - Run a short TensorFlow program

    `import tensorflow as tf
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))`
  - If the system outputs `Hello, TensorFlow!`, then you are ready to begin writing TensorFlow programs.

[image]
Good luck to you.

Comment: Hi @Noctis, the detailed instruction was very helpful. I am still running into problems. Installed CUDA-9.0, and cuDNN7.1.2 for CUDA-9.0. These 2 installations worked fine and passed all the post installation checks as posted in NVIDIA site. Then I installed tensorflow with GPU support per you instruction using the binary file (for Python3.6). It showed tensorflow and few other packages installed successfully. However, when I try to import tensorflow, I am getting the following error "Illegal instruction (core dumped)". Could it be due to the different cuDNN version? Thanks

Comment: Hi,@BonyPati. First time when i installed cuDNN7.1.2 and had get error. So,i follow official document installed cuDNN7.0.5.